# how to create a function that starts at the click event of the pie chart

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, pie-chart, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-chart

how to create a function that starts at the click event of the pie chart?

i would to pass the selected item to a function

```
<kendo-chart-series>
    <kendo-chart-series-item
           type="pie" [data]="dataSourcePieChart"
           categoryField="cost" field="cost">
           <kendo-chart-series-item-labels
              position="outsideEnd"
              color="#000"
              [content]="labelContent">
           </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
     </kendo-chart-series-item>
</kendo-chart-series>
```

[image]

Comment: I think this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49287125/angular-kendo-chart-click-event-to-pass-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind `seriesClick` event to `kendo-chart`.

[SeriesClickEvent](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/SeriesClickEvent/)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <kendo-chart (seriesClick)="seriesClick($event)">
      <kendo-chart-series>
        <kendo-chart-series-item  
            type="donut" [data]="data"
            categoryField="kind" field="share">
          <kendo-chart-series-item-labels
            [content]="labelContent"
            
            color="#fff" background="none">
          </kendo-chart-series-item-labels>
        </kendo-chart-series-item>
      </kendo-chart-series>
      <kendo-chart-legend [visible]="false"></kendo-chart-legend>
    </kendo-chart>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  public data: any[] = [{
    kind: 'Hydroelectric', share: 0.175
  }, {
    kind: 'Nuclear', share: 0.238
  }, {
    kind: 'Coal', share: 0.118
  }, {
    kind: 'Solar', share: 0.052
  }, {
    kind: 'Wind', share: 0.225
  }, {
    kind: 'Other', share: 0.192
  }];

  public labelContent(e: any): string {
    return e.category;
  }
  
  public seriesClick(e: any): void {
      console.log(e.category)
  }
}
```

Example: [seriesClick](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s2ducw?file=app/app.component.ts)